# How to find what packages need ESM update

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager, esm

When I log into my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system, I get this message:

```
5 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm
```

My question is how I find out what packages need these ESM updates. I thought the answer was "apt update && apt upgrade" but this does not show that any updates are needed:

```
# apt update && apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How do I figure out what 5 packages need ESM security updates? If they aren't packages I use, I'll just delete them.

EDIT for additional clarity: I'm not trying to update the packages. I'm trying to get a list of them so I can delete them if I don't use them.

Comment: Please provide output of `pro status` - this will show if Ubuntu Pro (advantage) is installed and which status.

Comment: I definitely do not have pro, nor do I want it, nor am I eligible for a free account for it. However the machine "knows" that 5 packages need ESM updates even though I don't have pro, so it seems logical that there would be a way to get a list of what those 5 packages are so I can remove them.

Comment: Thanks for reading Nmath :) I'm not trying to update the packages, I'm trying to get a list of them so I can remove them.

Comment: @DDP would you give us an update on your removal efforts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ua security-status --esm-apps
```

Package names in bold currently have an available update.

Comment: Thank you! This is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

ESM is a feature of Ubuntu Pro, which is a proprietary product so our insight is minimal.

As your sources suggest that you are not subscribed to Ubuntu Pro, you cannot see the names of the individual packages, nor access those ESM security updates anyway; they are simply not in the standard (free) Ubuntu repos.

- 18.04 users should be migrating to a newer release. Standard Support ends in three short months. After that, no more (free) non-ESM security updates, and we won't answer questions about 18.04 anymore!
- 18.04 Security updates for `bionic-security/main` end in April 2023. When Standard Support ends, new security updates will go to ESM instead, available only to subscribers.
- 18.04 Security updates for `bionic-security/universe` are already in ESM, available only to subscribers. Security in Universe is a community responsibility, so it often doesn't get done during the years of an LTS. Hence the market opportunity for Pro.

Since 18.04 --as of this writing-- is still in Standard Support, it is likely that the mentioned ESM packages are from the Universe repository. Audit the software that you added **after** install from the Universe pocket of the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Very well said.

Answer (score 0):

For `sudo apt update` to show these updates, you would have to add the esm repositories to your sources, which involves signing up for an free [account](https://ubuntu.com/pro).

I did this for my elderly relative's 18.04 system, since learning a new desktop is not an option for them, and it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the comment. Unfortunately it's only free for personal use, and this is not a personal use situation. My thinking is that my machine "knows" that there are five packages that need updating, so this information is on my machine somewhere even though I don't have a pro account. I just need to find where the information is.

Comment: @Nmath at least in 18.04 (which the OP is asking about) the repos didn't get added until I attached the machine to a subscription and enabled the features. No idea about 22.04